# Emulator doesn't trow event about orientation change from second time

Tags: android, android-emulator

on home computer emulator, the change of screen orientation from second time does nothing. I mean, that for the source code

```
WindowManager wm = getWindowManager(); 
Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay(); 
int orientation = d.getOrientation();
```

the first press on Cntrl+F11 changes orientation value from 0 to 1, for all other presses on Cntrl+F11, it remains with same value1.
On class computer (same package installation) it works fine. Any ideas why on home computer same program gives bug? Thanks.

Comment: I found the root cause for this bug. The avd device target was Android 2.3.3. I created a new avd device with target Android 2.1 and it works fine now.